# pGina fork - RDP Connection with User of Domain Controller in Windows Server 2008 or 2012

Tags: windows

When I am trying to login with a user of domain controller, pGina throw this message: "the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer".

The LDAP plugin has configured the Authentication, Gateway( rule with add user to group "Remote Desktop Users" ) and General Information tabs. After trying to login I verify the user´s groups in the machine and the user was added to the group "Remote Desktop Users".

Details:
-> pGina.fork 3.9.9.7 installed.
-> In the logs I don't see any error event.
-> the logs show that the user was successfully added to the "Remote Desktop Users" group.

This behavior only happens on Windows Server(2008 and 2012), with other operative systems( Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10 ), it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: the idea is that somebody has the solution for this case.